# How to declare a char array by using a variable as its size?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

```
char* mystrcat2(char* source, char* target) {
    int count = strlen(source) + strlen(target) + 1;
    char arr[count];
    //...
}
```

I want to create a char array, but VS2013 told me a error, the count should be a constant.I used VS2013 and this is a win32 console application with C++.

if the code like this is OK:

```
char arr[100];
```

How to declare a char array with a variable?
recently I'm learning C by reading "The C Programming Language"

Comment: Hint: read about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Use `std::string` when programming with C++. In C use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Length_Array).

Comment: C++ has `std::vector`

Comment: **Decide:** do you compile as C, or as C++ (as an side, VC++ only has a bad and dated C mode, and they are somewhat confused about what is C++ and what is C++/CLI). Tag appropriately.

Comment: Are you learning C or C++? In C++ you can use std::string which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @Kross please decide, if it's c++ I will delete my answer, it wouldn't even compile in c++.

Comment: The question was "How to declare a char array with a variable?", not "should I use a std::string or array".

Comment: try with stl::vectors, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 2):

You can always use dynamic allocation

```
char  *array;
size_t length;

length = strlen(source) + strlen(target) + 1;
array  = malloc(length);
if (array == NULL)
    abort_DoNot_Use_array();
/* use `array' here */
free(array); /* don't forget this */
```

Answer (score 2):

Your exact question was

> How to declare a char array with a variable?

Therefore, even though it is often better to use a std::string in C++, I will answer your exact question (under C++ assumption, since you already have a C-answer (malloc/free).

There are no variable sized arrays in C++, for that we have the STL class std::vector. What you need to do is allocate memory dynamically.

Example:

```
char* mystrcat2(char* source, char* target)
{
    char* pChar = new char[strlen(source) + strlen(target) + 1];
    // ...
    return pChar;
}
```

When you are finished with the char-pointer returned from this function you must not forget to call

```
delete[] pChar;
```

Remark: In C++11 it is typically not recommended to use raw pointers (like we do in this example), because you have automatic resource management via std::unique_ptr (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Being new to C++ I would recommend to use std::string instead of char*. Your code could be something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string mystrcat2(const string& source, const string& target) {
    return source + target;
}

int main() {
    cout << mystrcat2("Peter", "Kamps");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`g++` allows **C99** Variable Length Arrays in `C++` as a language extension. But it is not supported in standard `C++`.

the best options are `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this

```
char * mystrcat2(char * source, char * target) {
    std::string result(source);
    result += target;
    return result.c_str();
}
```

A C++11 version

```
char * mystrcat2(char * source, char * target) {
    return (to_string(source) + target).c_str();
}
```